# Is there any way to access the information on a atribute text inside a block object ? (Autolisp)

Tags: autolisp

Basically, I want a function that goes through the drawing and searchs for attribute definition text, I can do it normally, but if I make a block with said attribute text the function can't find them anymore. I don't know if it's even possible to do it.

Comment: For sure there is a way to do it (if I understand what You want to do ) . But "normally" may be understood in many differed ways. Show us some code.

Comment: I'm using mr lee's block counter (http://www.lee-mac.com/blockcounter.html), and I plan to modify this function in a way that the counting will distinguish simillar blocks with different atributte text on them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your task, you'll want to look at the value (Textstring property) of the attribute *references*, as opposed to the attribute *definitions*.

Attribute references are held by the block reference and their values may vary between multiple references of the same block, whereas attribute *definitions* reside within the single block *definition* (i.e. the blueprint for the block) and hold an optional default value.

The attribute references may be accessed either through Vanilla AutoLISP using the `entnext` function to iterate over the attribute reference subentities which follow a block reference entity in the drawing database ([example](http://lee-mac.com/attributefunctions.html#algetattributevaluerc)), or through Visual LISP by invoking the ActiveX `getattributes` method ([example](http://lee-mac.com/attributefunctions.html#vlgetattributevalue)).

My existing [Count Attribute Values](http://lee-mac.com/countattributevalues.html) program should provide some insight into how to accomplish this - you'll only need to differentiate the references by block name in addition to attribute value.